# How do I make a third generation iPod work with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, ipod, compatibility

I have a [third generation 40GB iPod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRy6.jpg) which I've been having some trouble getting to work with Windows 7 (RC).

iTunes and all other relevant software is installed correctly and indeed, the iPod itself works if the device is plugged in as the system reboots. However, after ejecting and using the iPod, plugging it back in results in a USB Device Unrecognised error and the iPod remains on the main menu before switching to the Charging screen. Only rebooting and having the device in from before Windows is running (where it is recognised by the BIOS) works.

It previously also worked fine on my Windows Vista installation on the same hardware and trying different ports has no effect.

How can I get the system to recognise the device without needing to restart?

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in after Windows reboots?

Comment: Um.. yes, that is when it fails to work, as I described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success in making this work by unplugging and replugging the iPod several times in quick succession until the Do Not Disconnect screen suddenly appears. Its not ideal but it does work.

Comment: definitely not ideal; sounds like a good way to wear out your port.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being the messenger of bad news, but for now, the only solution I found, is to install "Win7 XP mode virtual machine" from win7 web page and use it as a proxy between iTunes and your iPod.
Before that, I've tried everything to get iTunes to work and recognize my iPod (Touch, 3.0, 1st gen) on Win7 RTM x64, and nothing else worked.

(This problem reminds me when the same thing happened with Vista, when it was new, but then a number of people got BSODs after installing iTunes and rebooting, so you gotta wonder - will iTunes EVER work properly with Microsoft OSes?)

Comment: I also remember it having similar problems during the Vista beta and then it all suddenly started working fine with the RTM. Can live in hope I guess of something similar this time around.